# How to fix jQuery mobile cache issue?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I've noticed that there are a lot of different cache issues with jQuery Mobile, but I have been unsuccessful finding a solution to this one.  In essence, my app is loading a much older version of a script from a jQuery Mobile page every time the back button is pressed.

The start screen of my app has a search using a few different filters, at least one of them is required.  I have a bit of jquery to require this.  On the first time a user visits the start screen there is no problem at all, however if the user hits the back button and tries to search again, the jQuery validation is from a version from days ago and no longer works.

The same problem exists on the first load of a page somewhere else in the app, but may not be related.

Details:  Latest stable jQuery Mobile (1.1), jQuery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to load a page without pulling the cached version, add `data-ajax="false"` to the link.

```
<a href="page-two.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Page Two</a>
```

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html